# Gradle not finding dependencies

Tags: java, spring-boot, gradle, dependencies

I'm working on moving my project's build from Maven to Gradle, and using Kotlin as the DSL within Gradle. Here is [my working branch](https://github.com/mcpierce/comixed/tree/feature/issue-1444). The project currently is a multi-module project, and I'm using the `gradle-root` subdirectory in the repo to slowly migrate each module over to using Gradle. The project is Spring Boot based.

The issue I'm hitting at the moment is with the first submodule I'm trying to move, which is the data model (`comixed-model`, which has no project dependencies). I can figure out how to tell Gradle how to get the dependencies it needs, such as Jackson FasterXML.

I've configured the project to use the Spring Boot plugin. But the FasterXML dependencies aren't being found. Instead, I get:

```
-> % gradle clean build
> Task :comixed-model:compileJava FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':comixed-model:compileJava'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':comixed-model:compileClasspath'.
   > Could not find com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:.
     Required by:
         project :comixed-model
   > Could not find com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:.
     Required by:
         project :comixed-model
   > Could not find com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat:jackson-dataformat-xml:.
     Required by:
         project :comixed-model

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 616ms
15 actionable tasks: 5 executed, 10 up-to-date
```

I'm not sure what I've done wrong, and Googling doesn't seem to be showing me any solutions.

Comment: As a start, I would try to add it manually, like `implementation group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core', name: 'jackson-databind', version: '2.13.5'`, same for annotations and dataformat-xml ..

Comment: But, where do I add it? Which build file would make it available to the comixed-model project and anything that depends on it?